# Why do I get random garbage values in this simple program?

Tags: c

I want to read some number from the terminal and print them afterwards.
However, they all seem to be some kind of random value instead of the one I supplied.

Why doesn't my input get saved correctly?

```
int main (void)
{    
    int i = 0 , numeros[21] , cont = 1, z = 0;

    puts("\n === Bienvenido ===\n"); 
    puts("\n === Vamos a procesadar  un numero de serie de 20 digitos [Numericos] ===\n");  
    puts("\n === Dime los numeros ===\n"); 

    while (cont != 20 )
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &numeros[i]);      

        printf("\n === Dime otro numero. Numeros: %d ===\n", cont); 
        cont++;
    }
    for (z = 0; z < 20; z++)
    {
        printf("\nLos numeros son: %d\n", numeros[z]);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` == undefined behaviour. Don't do that

Comment: `scanf("%d", &numeros[i++]);`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, a couple of issues:

- `numeros` is declared as an array of 21 ints, but you're using it as if it were `numeros[20]`
- Undefined behaviour because you're calling `fflush` on `stdin`
- `scanf("%d", &numeros[i])`, though unsafe, is all fine and dandy, but `i` is never incremented
- Check return values of functions... always: `scanf` returns the number of values it scanned, if it returns 0, no `%d` was scanned, and `numeros[i]` needs to be reassigned.

Here's an example of how I'd write your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void )
{
    int c,i=0,
        numbers[20],
        count=0;
    //puts adds new line
    puts("enter 20 numbers");
    while(count < 20)
    {
        c = scanf(" %d", &numbers[i]);//note the format: "<space>%d"
        if (c)
        {//c is 1 if a number was read
            ++i;//increment i,
            ++count;//and increment count
        }
        //clear stdin, any trailing chars should be ignored
        while ((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            ;
    }
    for (i=0;i<count;++i)
        printf("Number %d: %d\n", i+1, numbers[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing `i` in the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `cont`, but using `numeros[i]` to store your input. As `i` never changes, you only write to the first array element. Change the `i` to `cont`, as in

```
scanf("%d", &numeros[cont]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to achieve? I see that you're putting into `i=0` index of your numeros array number from `stdin`. Then you're iterating trough this array, but you've just entered one number! You should propbably change the subsctript of your `numeros` array to cont like that:

```
scanf("%d", &numeros[cont]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d", &numeros[i]);
```

should be replaced with

```
scanf("%d", &numeros[cont]);
```

AS you are incrementing cont not i